# Exportreport plugin getting issue in ZAP2.12.x version in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-job-dsl, zap

I'm using **exportreport** plugins to export my report. Until the ZAP 2.9 version, It's working fine. Today I'm trying to update the ZAP version 2.12 and I'm getting the error.

Also, the plugin is not installed and ZAP will shut down automatically.

If there are any limitations to using this plugin in the ZAP 2.12 version? If its, does ZAP's latest version have any export support itself?

Comment: That add-on has been removed/discontinued. ZAP 2.12 requires min Java 11.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm also got the same from this link https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/export-report/